# over and critically damped systems settling time

Tags: control, control-system, transfer-function, step-response, damping-factor

I know that for second order systems the settling time(St) equation is:

[image: formula]

So my question is, should this same formula be used when the system is over or critically damped? Is it right to use it in that cases?

Comment: Settling time is normally: \$ T_s\approx \large \frac{4}{\zeta\omega _n}\$, and generally it doesn't work for \$\zeta > 1\$

Comment: So what should I use to find the settling time when ζ>1?

Comment: Solve the time function: unit step response  = 0.98 (for 2% settling time and unity gain system).

Comment: Ts is always determined by time at max % error to a step input. where Ts multiplies according to  ln (error ratio) e.g. ln(2%) =-3.9  ~4.  The damping factor,  ζ affect these approximations , and depends on 1 or 2 poles in a 2nd order system. This is different from Rise time which is   63% for Time constant RC=T or typically 10 to 90% for overdamped, but depends on % error again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

TL;DR: **NO, you can't use the underdamped settling time formula** to find out the settling time of an overdamped system. And you can't use it for a critically damped system either.

LONG FORM answer follows...

---

### Critically damped case

For the *critically damped case* (\$\zeta=1\$), the step response is:

$$
v_{out}(t) = H_0 u(t) \lbrack 1 - (1+\omega_0 t) e^{-\omega_0 t} \rbrack
$$

If we define the settling time \$T_s\$ using the same "within 2% of final response" criteria, then:

$$
0.02 = (1+\omega_0 T_s) e^{-\omega_0 T_s}\\
$$

Solving numerically for \$\omega_0 T_s\$ (by simply using Excel's solver) we obtain:

$$
T_s  \approx \frac{5.8335}{\omega_0}
$$

---

### Overdamped case

For the *overdamped case* (\$\zeta>1\$), the step response is:

$$
v_{out}(t) = H_0 u(t) \left[ 1 - \frac{s_2}{s_2-s_1}e^{s_1 t} - \frac{s_1}{s_1-s_2}e^{s_2 t}  \right] 
$$

where \$s_1, s_2\$ are the real roots of the transfer function denominator:

$$
s_1 = -\zeta \omega_0 + \omega_0 \sqrt{\zeta^2-1} \\
s_2 = -\zeta \omega_0 - \omega_0 \sqrt{\zeta^2-1}
$$

For convenience we define:

$$
\begin{align}
\Delta &= \frac{s_2-s_1}{2} = - \omega_0 \sqrt{\zeta^2-1} \\
\Sigma &= \frac{s_1+s_2}{2} = - \zeta \omega_0 \\
K &= \frac{\Sigma}{\Delta} = \frac{\zeta}{\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}}
\end{align}
$$

So that:

$$
\begin{align}
s_1 &= \Sigma-\Delta \\
s_2 &= \Sigma+\Delta
\end{align}
$$

If we define the settling time \$T_s\$ using the same "within 2% of final response" criteria, then:

$$
\begin{align}
0.02 &= \frac{s_2}{s_2-s_1} e^{s_1 T_s} + \frac{s_1}{s_1-s_2} e^{s_2 T_s} =  \\
&= \frac{\Sigma + \Delta}{2 \Delta} e^{(\Sigma - \Delta) T_s} - \frac{\Sigma - \Delta}{2 \Delta} e^{(\Sigma + \Delta) T_s} = \\
&= \frac{e^{\Sigma T_s}}{\Delta} \left[ \frac{\Sigma+\Delta}{2} e^{-\Delta T_s} - \frac{\Sigma-\Delta}{2} e^{\Delta T_s} \right] = \\
&= \frac{e^{\Sigma T_s}}{\Delta} \left[ \frac{\Delta}{2} \left( e^{\Delta T_s} + e^{-\Delta T_s} \right) - \frac{\Sigma}{2} \left( e^{\Delta T_s} - e^{-\Delta T_s} \right) \right] = \\
&= \frac{e^{\Sigma T_s}}{\Delta} \left[ \Delta \cosh{(\Delta T_s)} - \Sigma \sinh{(\Delta T_s)} \right] = \\
&= e^{K \Delta T_s} \left[ \cosh{(\Delta T_s)} - K \sinh{(\Delta T_s)} \right] = \\
&= e^{-K |\Delta| T_s} \left[ \cosh{(-|\Delta| T_s)} - K \sinh{(-|\Delta| T_s)} \right]
\end{align}
$$

And finally:

$$
0.02 = e^{-K |\Delta| T_s} \left[ \cosh{(|\Delta| T_s)} + K \sinh{(|\Delta| T_s)} \right] \\
$$

Now that we have rewritten the expression in term of \$ |\Delta| T_s\$ and \$K\$ (instead of in terms of \$s_1\$ and \$s_2\$), we can numerically solve for \$ |\Delta| T_s\$, (by simply using Excel's solver) for **any arbitrary** given \$\zeta>1\$.

**Example 1:** a moderately overdamped system with \$\zeta = 1.1\$. Thus \$K = \frac{1.1}{1.1^2-1} \approx 2.4\$, and then solving numerically:

$$
T_s  \approx \frac{3.172}{|\Delta|} = \frac{3.172}{\omega_0 \sqrt{1.1^2-1}} \approx \frac{6.922}{\omega_0}
$$

**Example 2:** a heavily overdamped system with \$\zeta = 5\$. Thus \$K = \frac{5}{\sqrt{24}} \approx 1.0206\$, and then solving numerically:

$$
T_s  \approx \frac{190.21}{|\Delta|} = \frac{190.21}{\omega_0 \sqrt{24}} \approx \frac{38.827}{\omega_0}
$$

---

There is also an approximation for **heavily overdamped** (\$\zeta \gg 1\$) systems based on the dominant pole:

$$
v_{out}(t) \approx H_0 u(t) \left[ 1 - e^{s_1 t} \right]
$$

If we define the settling time \$T_s\$ using the same "within 2% of final response" criteria, then:

$$
0.02 \approx e^{s_1 T_s}
$$

and:

$$
T_s \approx \frac{\ln(0.02)}{s_1} = \frac{-\ln(0.02)}{\omega_0 (\zeta-\sqrt{\zeta^2-1})}
$$

We can compare this approximation with the exact results that we have derived before.

For \$\zeta = 5\$:

$$
T_s  \approx \frac{38.725}{\omega_0}
$$

An estimation error just about -0.25%. Quite good indeed.

For \$\zeta = 1.1\$:

$$
T_s  \approx \frac{6.096}{\omega_0}
$$

An estimation error of approx -12%. Not bad taking into account that \$\zeta = 1.1\$ is just marginally above the critically damped case!.

---

### Bonus

We can write a generic settling time expression for \$\zeta>1\$ as follows

$$
T_s  = \frac{\psi}{\omega_0}
$$

where \$\psi\$ is a coefficient **roughly proportional** to the damping factor \$\zeta\$.

I've numerically calculated the value of \$\psi\$ for a range of \$1<\zeta<9\$ using the expression previously derived for settling within 2% of the final value,

$$
0.02 = e^{-K |\Delta| T_s} \left[ \cosh{(|\Delta| T_s)} + K \sinh{(|\Delta| T_s)} \right]
$$

Then I've calculated (for comparison purposes) 1) the dominant pole approximation, 2) a 3rd order polynomial regression on my numerically calculated dataset, and 3), 4) the relative error due to these two approximations.

Here is an Excel plot with the results:

[image: settling time inverse proportionality constant phi]

Comment: (jaw hits ground) +1 for epic answer.

Comment: Thank you. I considered calculating and plotting a set of curves representing a range of settling tolerance values (1%, 2%, 5%, 10%...) but then I thought it might be a bit excessive. :D

Comment: Thanks for great answer. As note, I was was solving equation for ζ=10 via secant method, and double got quickly overflown. If you having same problem, just unfold sinh and cosh by definition. I got: `0.5 * ((K + 1) * exp(x * (-K + 1)) + (-K + 1) * exp(x * (-K - 1))) - 0.02`, this doesn't overflow :)

Comment: @EnricBlanco Is there any general solution for finding Ts? I don't want to use Excel or WolframAlpha to calculate it, I know it has two roots by the graph. I've already find it for several hours but failed, I need to automate the calculation

Comment: @Unknown123 I’m afraid there is no closed-form expression, sorry.

Comment: @Unknown123 Use either the dominant pole or the polynomial approximation, if you can tolerate the error.

Comment: @EnricBlanco I've found closed-form expression for critically damped using Lambert W function branch -1 for both rise time and settling time. Only 0 and -1 produce real value, also the branch 0 produce negative value, it's illogical for settling time or rise time to be negative or complex, so I got the solution. But for overdamped, I'm still scratching my head.

Comment: @EnricBlanco Do you have wolfram alpha pro? Can you help me with this one? The standard computation time exceeded for me with this [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5BExp%5B-K*x%5D*(Cosh%5Bx%5D%2BK*Sinh%5Bx%5D)-0.02+%3D%3D+0+,+x%5D)

Comment: @Unknown123 Sorry, I don’t have or use Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: @EnricBlanco great answer, could you please provide any reference about your "bonus" approximation formula? Did you discover it through esperiment or Is it possibile to find a deeper motivation elsewhere?

Answer (score 3):

The settling time for the underdamped case is well known. I will present solutions for the other two cases (2% definition):

**1. Overdamped**

The general step response for 2 real and distinct poles \$p_1\$ and \$p_2\$ is:

$$ y_s(t)=K\left[1 - \frac{p_2}{p_2-p_1}e^{-p_1t} - \frac{p_1}{p_1-p_2}e^{-p_2t}\right]u(t) $$

Doing \$p_2=kp_1\$, where \$k\$ is a constant and writing in a normalized form, regardless of the final value \$K\$:

$$ \frac{y_s(t)}{K}=\left[1 - \frac{k}{k-1}e^{-p_1t} + \frac{1}{k-1}e^{-kp_1t}\right]u(t) $$

When \$t=t_s\$ (settling time), \$\frac{y_s(t_s)}{K}\$ is equal to 0.98, resulting in:

$$\frac{k}{k-1}e^{-p_1t_s} - \frac{1}{k-1}e^{-kp_1t_s} = 0.02 $$

This equation can be solved using numerical methods, for a normalized variable \$p_1t_s\$. The solution can be simplified if the existence of a **dominant pole** is admitted, for example \$p1\$, so that \$k \gg 1\$. In this case, the second term on left side vanishes fastly and \$\frac{k}{k-1}\simeq 1\$. Therefore:

$$e^{-p_1t_s} \simeq 0.02 $$

Solving for \$p_1t_s\$:

$$ p_1t_s \simeq 3.91 $$

or 
$$t_s \simeq \frac{3.91}{p_1} $$

Using the 5% definition: \$t_s \simeq\frac{3}{p_1}\$

**2. Critically damped**

In this case, the normalized response is:

$$ y_s(t)= K \left[ 1 - (1 + p_1t)e^{-p_1t}\right] $$

So:

$$ \frac{y_s(t)}{K}= 1-\left( 1 + p_1t \right)e^{-p_1t} $$

With a settling time \$t_s\$ (2% definition):

$$ 0.02 = (1+p_1t_s)e^{-p_1t_s} $$

This equation can be solved using numerical methods, for a normalized variable \$p_1t_s\$. With Newton-Raphson I got:

$$p_1t_s \simeq 5.83$$

or 
$$t_s \simeq \frac{5.83}{p_1} $$

Similarly, using the 5% definition: \$t_s \simeq\frac{4.74}{p_1}\$

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use the same formula. The reason being is when you change the poles you also change the settling time. If you solve the equations for a step input and look at the output each equation has different time constants because of the poles of the system.  See [here](http://ecee.colorado.edu/~ecen2270/materials/TransResp2ndOrdSys.pdf):

> In the critically damped case, the time constant 1/ω0 is smaller than the slower time constant 2ζ/ω0 of the overdamped case. In consequence, the response is faster. This is the fastest response that contains no overshoot and ringing.