# How to estimate settling time of an overdamped system?

Tags: control, control-system, transfer-function, step-response

I've been trying to figure out how to estimate the settling time of a second order system in response to a step input of magnitude 5.
The systems transfer function is $$G(s) = \frac{1}{(s+2)(s+4)}$$ and I have already determined the time response with the step input R(s): $$C(s)=R(s)G(s)\qquad \therefore c(t) = \frac{5}{8}+\frac{5}{8}e^{-4t}-\frac{5}{4}e^{-2t}$$
Now I need to estimate the 2% settling time of the response using this information, but I'm not sure how. I know the system is overdamped as ζ>1, so I can't use the normal settling time equation $$T_s =\frac{4}{\zeta\omega_n}$$
I looked into this post: ([over and critically damped systems settling time](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/296567/over-and-critically-damped-systems-settling-time)) but the answers only explain long winded ways to get an accurate result. I've already used MATLAB to obtain an exact result of 2.3 seconds, but I need to be able to estimate it without MATLAB.

I was thinking I could try trial and error with different values of *t* until *c(t)* is within 2% of the steady state value (which is 0.625) but while this would work I doubt its the correct way to do it, so is anyone able to help me out with a better method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For systems with real left-half plane poles, you can usually estimate it by only considering the dominant pole (the pole with the lowest frequency). In your case this would be \$p_d=-2\$. The result gets more accurate as the non-dominant pole (\$p_{nd}\$) moves further away from the dominant pole.

By only considering the dominant pole, you get a rather simple equation:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{5}{4}\cdot e^{-2t}&=0.02\cdot \frac{5}{8} \\
t &= -\frac{1}{2}\cdot \ln\left( 0.02\cdot \frac{5}{8}\cdot \frac{4}{5} \right) \approx 2.30258509299s\\
\end{align}$$

The idea is that the non-dominant pole at \$p_{nd}=-4\$ leads to a term \$e^{-4t}\$ which will be damping so quickly that it doesn't affect the overall settling time. The advantage is the simplicity of the equation, and the fact that is actually a pretty common occurrence to have a very dominant pole and far-away non-dominant poles in electronic circuits.

In your specific case, it is possible to analytically calculate the settling time. The time it takes for the time-dependent terms to damp to 2% of the final value can be calculated using (similar to Andy's answer, but using the absolute value):

$$\begin{align}
\left| e^{-4t}-2\cdot e^{-2t} \right| &=0.02 \\
&\Updownarrow (y=e^{-2t})\\
y^2-2\cdot y &= \pm 0.02 \\
&\Updownarrow (\text{There are 4 distinct solutions, but I only take the relevant one}) \\
y = e^{-2t} &= 1 - \frac{7}{5\sqrt{2}} \\
&\Updownarrow \\
t &= -\frac{1}{2}\cdot \ln\left(1 - \frac{7}{5\sqrt{2}}\right) \approx 2.30006613189s
\end{align}$$

So a factor of 2 for \$p_{nd}/p_d\$ leads to about an error of 0.1% on the calculated settling time when using the dominant-pole approximation. Whether or not this is sufficient I leave to you.

Comment: Thats perfect thankyou!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, your inverse Laplace calculation is correct.

The final steady state value will be 5/8 - this is the DC value after a long length of time. So, you are really looking for the rest of the equation to fall in magnitude to 2% of 5/8: -

$$\dfrac{5}{8}e^{-4t} - \dfrac{5}{4}e^{-2t} = \dfrac{5}{8}\cdot \text{0.02}$$

$$=\dfrac{8}{8}e^{-4t} - \dfrac{8}{4}e^{-2t} = \dfrac{8}{8}\cdot \text{0.02}$$

$$= e^{-4t} - 2e^{-2t} = 0.02$$

Does that help?

Comment: I was pretty close then as I was just doing a similar thing to this, but I was using 0.98 instead of 0.02. Why do you use 2% and not 98%? Surely if we want 2% less than the final value then it would be 0.98 x 5/8?

Comment: @Sam your approach and mine are equally valid, it's just I thought one way and you thought the other.

Comment: We would have to use \$-0.02\$ instead of \$+0.02\$ to find the correct settling time (or invert the coefficients of the exponentials, or use the 0.98 @Sam proposed and include the DC term). Probably an oversight, but perhaps the source of the confusion?

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's solve this in a more general case. We have the following transfer function (assuming real positive value for \$\epsilon\$):

$$\mathcal{H}\left(\text{s}\right):=\frac{\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{X}\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{1}{\left(\text{s}+\epsilon\right)\left(\text{s}+2\epsilon\right)}\tag1$$

When we look at the step-response we are using \$\text{X}\left(\text{s}\right)=\mathcal{L}_t\left[\theta\left(t\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{1}{\text{s}}\$, so the output is given by:

$$\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{1}{\text{s}}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(\text{s}+\epsilon\right)\left(\text{s}+2\epsilon\right)}\tag2$$

Using inverse Laplace transform, we find:

$$\text{y}\left(t\right)=\mathcal{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{\text{s}}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(\text{s}+\epsilon\right)\left(\text{s}+2\epsilon\right)}\right]_{\left(t\right)}=\frac{\exp\left(-2\epsilon t\right)\left(\exp\left(\epsilon t\right)-1\right)^2}{2\epsilon^2}\tag3$$

It is not hard to show that when \$t\to\infty\$ (assuming real positive value for \$\epsilon\$), we get:

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\text{y}\left(t\right)=\frac{1}{2\epsilon^2}\tag4$$

Now, for the settling time, we want to find the time \$t\$ when \$\text{n}\text{%}\$ of the final value is reached:

$$\text{y}\left(t_\text{n}\right)=\frac{\text{n}\text{%}}{100}\cdot\frac{1}{2\epsilon^2}\Longleftrightarrow\space t_\text{n}=\dots\tag5$$

Solving that gives:

$$t_\text{n}=\frac{1}{\epsilon}\cdot\ln\left(\frac{10}{10-\sqrt{\text{n}\text{%}}}\right)\tag6$$